# SQL: How to Group By task and choose only those that are completed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I would need to make query from todo list the next way.

```
ID  Date       Status  Phase
1   21.1.2017  Done    1
1   22.1 2017  Done    2
2   20.1.2017  Done    1
2   22.1.2017  Undone  2
3   23.1.2017  Undone  1
3   25.1.2017  Undone  2
```

So I need to find those Task that are Done (all Statuses are Done) and then take the last date so MAX(Date)? I don't need to the Phase info.

Result should be

```
ID  Date       Status 
1   22.1 2017  Done
```

Can you please help me how to Group by, take the MAX(Date) but also make some rule that all Statuses are Done?

Comment: Is Phase the ID of the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one method:

```
select t.id, max(t.date) as date, max(t.status) as status
from t
group by t.id
having min(t.status) = max(t.status) and min(t.status) = 'Done';
```

Comment: But this query not returns any date. If change third rows date to 23 it still return ID = 1

Comment: @arslanaybars . . . The third row has an `id = 2`.  That is independent of `id = 1`, so changing the date in that row has no effect on other ids.  I added the additional columns (the OP seemed to know how to get those values).

Comment: @GordonLinoff But according to the question, for example, if third-row data is '23.1.2017' then "id" should be 2, because its "Status" is "Done" too and has max date. If I understood correctly, the question is, find correct id according to max Date and Status = "Done".

Answer (score 4):

You can use this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ID], [Date], [Status] FROM MyTable 
    WHERE [Status] ='Done'
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```